Problem with reading binary data from networkStream object
regarding to my needs to get binary data from SCPI Lan linked to some measurement equipment,
first I tried using StreamReader object like this:
public async Task<string> Transmit ()
{
    IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 0, 21 });
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

    await client.ConnectAsync(ipAddress, 5555); // Connect

    NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(networkStream);

    writer.AutoFlush = true;
    
    //SEND Command to Machine
    await writer.WriteLineAsync("WAV:READ?" + "\n");

    //Receive Data from Machine
    string respond= await reader.ReadLineAsync();

    return respond;
}

it works fine, but the problem is real data send in binary format and as I found out StreamReader can not handle binary data, also I tried to change different Unicodes like UTF8 and again all datas bigger than 127 changes to 65536 when I try to convert string to binary by :
byte[] RawData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
so I tried using BinaryReader that not supports asyncRead, so I tried to using polling method by checking DataAvailable property in networkSteam object like this:
//...
 while (true)
    {
        if (networkStream.DataAvailable)
        {
            byte b = binaryReader.ReadByte();
            //.. do grabbing data and find EOP by dispatching data packet 
            //.. size could varies 
            //.. if(EOP)
            //.. {
            //..     break;
            //.. }
        }
    }

but networkStream.DataAvailable  never turns true , also I had no chance to get any byte from binaryReader.ReadByte() even without checking DataAvailable prop.
also regarding to my project its important to support async method that seems not supported by binaryReader ;
my code is running under .NetFramework 4.6.
does any one have any suggestion to help me to solve my problem please?

You already have a NetworkStream there, why did you try to use the specialized StreamReader, which deals with sequences of characters, when you know you're going to receive bytes that don't represent encoded strings?

Streams already handle binary data. StreamReader is for decoding that into text. Just ditch it and use the stream directly.

NetworkStream already has a ReadAsync() courtesy of it's parent class, Stream

thanks all, @Jimi I tried NetworkStream  before. its weird. WriteAsync function works and I receive any thing I sent, in listener, but ds=await networkStream.ReadAsync(responseData,offset,1); get stuck and never return any respond even I change size to 1.

I don't see your implementation. Remove all intermediate Streams (StreamReader AND StreamWriter), pass a CancellationToken => because you should test this targeting at least .NET 6 (better .NET 7) if possible. The NetworkStream, in these versions, overrides the base Stream behavior, to implement a slightly different method, more reliable in async/await. In .NET Framework, it doesn't

As already noted in the comments: forget about StreamReader/StreamWriter; they're for text, and you're not reading (pure) text. You're going to need to use the Stream API directly (in particular ReadAsync and WriteAsync), and deal with the rest yourself; in particular, when reading you'll typically be working with a read-buffer, and you need to deal with handling a back-buffer of as-yet-unconsumed data, detecting individual chunks/frames, etc. When dealing with text sub-data, Encoding comes into play.

Which could be summarized as "you need to implement the protocol of your equipment", right?

@Fildor sure; although whenever possible, first check whether someone else has already written a suitable implementation; most people under-estimate the nuance involved in a good implementation of a protocol parser/formatter; a minimal implementation that you can bash out in a day and works for a few sample cases might look like it deals with "most" of the problem, but that final push between "most" and "good/all" can be huge, as in "fundamentally different approaches needed, with a completely different mental model of the problem"

" first check whether someone else has already written a suitable implementation;" - Of course. I somehow made the presupposition there is no such preexisting work available. For protocols, I'd always try to stand on the shoulders of giants if ever so possible. Even if it's a nieche thing and the lib has minor bugs, I'd probably prefer contributing to the project to fix them instead of starting from scratch.

thanks, yes and I tried, but problem is the respond packet size is not fixed, and mentioned inside received data. in my implementation, process get stucked in 'ReadAsync()' function. when I try to read fixed size data chunks by code like 'await ReadAsync(buf,0,1024);' it never return. to make a back buffer I should copy received data to other buffer chunk by chunk. but its never ends awaited 'ReadAsync()' function with size argument bigger than real sent data. as a hardware programmer, I'm not perfect in C# and it could be a real ridiculous question.

@Fildor as a hardware C++ programmer I always prefer to write Libs by myself unless it was an Official library or Standard protocol Lib. reason is, in hardware any code bug can deal huge damage. so developers must to dominate every bit changes in the code. but in this case, I want to connect my oscilloscope to an app the control my hardware with PC. the protocol is standard and called SCPI language. most of commands ( almost all ) is ASCII. just in this case I want grab huge amount of analog data that is binary and 400MB per transaction.

@EhsanDaneshvar did you set the ReadTimeout, cause your description sounds like it was in its default value of Infinite.

@EhsanDaneshvar I programmed Robots, so I get the point about hardware (and I actually had to pull out a factory worker once before she got her arm broken, nearly). In this case, though, it may actually be beneficial to look for an "official" SCPI nuget.

^^ Using Nuget Gallery and searching for "SCPI" provides quite a variety of Libraries. The first hit actually describes itself as "is a pure C#.NET library for connecting measurement instruments talking the SCPI commands over USB or Ethernet." and is tagged "Oscilloscope". Sounds like what you want.

@EhsanDaneshvar Stream.ReadAsync should only block until "some" data is available - it  doesn't attempt to fill the buffer, as it is expected to be used in dialog APIs (sockets, etc) where both ends need to respond - however, if for some reason that isn't playing ball, you can always read byte-by-byte, at least until you have whatever frame data you need to know the actual frame size (unless it is a sentinel / terminated protocol, typical of text-adjacent protocols)

@NPras yes I tried but make not difference.
